# Joomla 1.0 issue with com_frontpage and RSS reader

Tags: php, joomla, rss, rss-reader

I have a 99% working RSS reader in PHP built into my joomla frontpage, but regardless of any published article the newest (i.e. top of the list) always has the following code built into the url.. the url works ok, but looks very untidy.

```
option=com_frontpage&Itemid=56
```

so my rss link looks like this:

```
    <a href="option=com_frontpage&Itemid=56http://www........">title</a>
```

the http://www... is the correct link but for some unknown reason joomla is adding this component link to it.

all other rss links don't have this.
there is no issues in the rss script. checked, double checked, checked by someone else.

it must be something happening in joomla.

any one got any ideas.

thanks

p.s. i know it's joomla 1.0 and very bad. but it's a heavily modified backend in other areas so not effecting this and is on an internal server only.

Comment: Have you tried to view the code that generate this output?

Comment: yes the code is php and fail basic set of classes and functions, there is no sign of this in the markup, so must be added by joomla is some bizarre way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added this code into the function to check for the prepending annoyance and remove it.

```
            if($this->link)
        {
    //check for multiple http
    if($index == 0 && !preg_match("/^http/i", $this->link)){
    $this->link = substr($this->link, strpos($this->link, 'http'));
        }
```